# Pass an argument to an AIDL

Tags: java, android, function, aidl

I have a function in my AIDL file

```
int getAvailableTokens(out List<String> list);
```

From the main class I want to call this function and give as argument `List<String> mylist` in order function will set it. How I can do that ?

#### EDITED

```
int getAvailableTokens (List<FidoTokenInfo> list) throws RemoteException {
    // EDITED: The list must be set in this way!!!
    list.addAll(mFidoDsm.getList());
    // THIS WAY IS NOT CORRECT !!!
    // list = mFidoDsm.getList();
    Log.i(TAG, "list .size() = " + list.size()); // here list size is 1.
}


// First this function calles.
public List<FidoTokenInfo> getAllTokens () throws FidoException {
    List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();;

    try {
       int error = dsmService().getAvailableTokens(tokenList);
       Log.i(TAG, "tokenList.size() = " + tokenList.size()); // here list size is 0.
       return tokenList;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
```

Okey I have made some changes and here is my code, as you can see I call `getAvailableTokens` function from `getAllTokens` function and pass as an argument to `getAvailableTokens` list `tokenList` then in `getAvailableTokens` I set that list and then I check size it is 1, but when I check size of list `tokenList` it is 0 but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .aidl file you should add `inout` instead of `out`. In this case, in your main class you should initialize the list:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
int error = getAvailableTokens(mylist);
int size = myList.size();
```

Comment: In your aidl file you should have the following declaration: int getAvailableTokens(inout List<String> list); Do not forget to change it to inout, not only out.

Comment: The main reason of error was that I set list in this way `list=mFidoDsm.getList()` instead of `list.addAll(mFidoDsm.getList());`

Comment: and can I write `int getAvailableTokens(out MyClass list);` ? there `MyClass` is class created by me ?

Comment: Only iff MyClass implements Parcelable interface.